# Methods in researching loss of natural habitat

Tags: ecology

What methods are there to research loss of natural habitat?

I know of supervised image classification in GIS but what other methods are commonly used in research?

Comment: Probably a good place to start would be: http://jncc.defra.gov.uk/default.aspx?page=2183&q=Habitat%20monitoring

Comment: thanks @nmtoken the 'monitoring' keyword opens new worlds!